# wanted to decrement remaining time with 1 sec accuracy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var valr5 = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = valr5;
        
        if (valr5 == '00:00'){
            window.location = "index.php";
        }   
    }
};
```

On Ajax call, in return responseText, I am getting remaining minutes and seconds in this format '1.30'. (it can be anything like '00.28' in place of '1.30')

I wanted decrement it by 1 till '00:00' but with accuracy of 1 sec and show that countdown in  "countdown" div

Please can anyone guide me on this.

Comment: You should have the server send a timestamp instead, then calculate the remaining hours, minutes and seconds. Use `setInterval` to update the <div>.